# pre populate multiple records

Tags: php, cakephp

I can pre-populate a form of 1 record but i cant get  multiple records to pre-populate a form.
I want to pre-populate all the records from an ID of which there will be about 6-10 rows.

I get the required form fields to display (about 7 records as expected) but nothing in the textboxes.
The docs are not clear about multiple records in this case.

Also I need save only a few of these records

```
  public function availtmped($id = null) {
     $this->loadModel('AvailabilityForTutor');

   ....
         if ($this->request->is('post')) {
             $this->Availtmp->create();
              $tutoredit = array('Availtmp' => $this->request->data['AvailablityForTutor']);
                 $tutoredit['Availtmp']['id']=NULL;
           $tutoredit['Availtmp']['tutor_id']=$id;;

               if ($this->Availtmp->save($tutoredit)) {
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('The tutor details to be edited have ben forwarded to management'), 'flash_success');
               // $this->redirect(array('controller'=> 'tutors' , 'action' => 'tutordetails'));
            } else {
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('The tutor edit details could not be saved. Please, try again.'), 'flash_alert');
            }
        } else {
           // $this->request->data = $this->AvailablityForTutor->read(null, $id);
        }

      $tutor_id = $id;
        $tutor =$this->AvailabilityForTutor->find('all',array(  'conditions'=>array('tutor_id'=> $tutorId)));
        $this->request->data=$tutor;

view//  UPDATE - I can populate with weekday but not time field as I just get the wrong start/end time

      echo $this->Form->create('AvailablityForTutor', array('type' => 'post'));  

             foreach ($tutor as $key => $item):
          echo $this->Form->input('AvailabilityForTutor.'.$key.'.weekday', 
                                    array('value'=>$this->request->data[$key]        echo $this->Form->input('weekday', 
                                        array('value'=>$this->request->data[$key]['AvailabilityForTutor']['weekday']));
               echo $this->Form->input('start_time', 
                                        array('value'=>$this->request->data[$key]['AvailabilityForTutor']['start_time']));

              echo $this->Form->input('end_time', 
                                        array('value'=>$this->request->data[$key]['AvailabilityForTutor']['end_time']));


           echo $this->Form->end('Save Edit Request');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the below method it is very basic but you can follow through it

```
 foreach ($tutor as $key => $item):
      echo $this->Form->input('AvailabilityForTutor.'.$key.'.weekday', array('value'=>$this->request->data[$key]['AvailabilityForTutor']['weekday']));
      echo $this->Form->hidden('AvailabilityForTutor.'.$key.'.id', array('value'=>$this->request->data[$key]['AvailabilityForTutor']['id']));
 endforeach;
```

Comment: How do i get the id from this method when saving as i need to add in extra fields on each record at controller level before saving

Comment: This totally negates the benefits of using the Form helper IMO.

Comment: okay , lets provide the best available method if you have the same query as OP

Comment: I have updated what I get now in the view. I cant populate with the correct start/end time as I get the same time in every time field

Comment: I can get the time to display in a time field   echo $this->Form->input('start_time', 
                                                array('type' => 'time', 'selected'=>$this->request->data[$key]['AvailabilityForTutor']['start_time']));